# Question re. catapult effect

Tags: electromagnetism

I am researching [the catapult effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catapult_effect), but there are few things I can't seem to find the answer to. I'm trying to find out why when two magnetic fields interact (a magnetic field from a conductor and another magnetic field from a permanent magnet), the resultant field (the catapult field) appears distorted. Is it something to do with the direction of the individual fields and the way they interact with each other? Additionally, why is it that the conductor moves in the direction it does? Why is it inclined to move in the direction of weaker magnetic field/flux?

Answer (score 0):

The resultant magnetic field is the vector addition of the magnetic field due to the permanent magnet and the magnetic field due to the current carrying wire.

[image]

The diagram above tries to illustrate this addition of the two magnetic fields.
Above the wire the magnetic fields from the permanent magnet and the wire are in the same direction and so add together t produce a larger magnetic field whereas below the wire the magnetic fields are in opposite directions and so produce a weaker field even to the extent that there is a point below the wire, called the neutral point, where the magnetic field is zero.

The direction of the force on the wire can be found in a number of ways one of which is illustrated below.

[image].

[Faraday gave the magnetic field lines some properties](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#Magnetic_field_lines) which included the fact that they repelled one another and they were always in a state of tension (like rubber bands) and if you look at the "catapult" field (top right diagram) you can see where the name comes from.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations…

"Is [the distorted field] something to do with the direction of the individual fields and the way they interact with each other?" Very much so: the resultant magnetic field at each point P is the vector sum of the uniform field and the field at point P due to the current-carrying wire. [I'd recommend choosing one or two points and sketching vector addition diagrams to convince yourself of this.]

"Additionally, why is it that the conductor moves in the direction it does?" I think that most physicists wouldn't try to understand this in terms of the catapult effect. They wouldn't, indeed, concern themselves with the *resultant* field, but would just consider the 'externally generated' (uniform) field, $\vec {B_{ext}}$ and the motor effect (or Lorentz) force, given by $I \vec{L} \times \vec{B_{ext}}$

"Why is it inclined to move in the direction of weaker magnetic field/flux?" I've side-stepped this, and would like to learn of a deeper reason for the catapult effect and 'mechanical' properties of field lines in general. The only little bit of insight I can offer is that the effect can be related to the more general principle that a circuit (current carrying loop) in an external field tends to change shape and/or orientation in such a way as to maximise the resultant (total) magnetic flux linked with the circuit. [For example, if you have a loop of wire as drawn on a page, with current circulating clockwise round it, as seen from above, and a uniform external field going into the page, the field due to the loop will, inside the loop, re-inforce the uniform field, but, also, the motor effect forces on each bit of the loop will be outwards, tending to expand the loop, and therefore to increase the total flux linked with it. The re-inforced field in the loop appears on a diagram as stretched fibres of the catapult.]